# Dynamically sorting the asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a Gridview in my application in asp.net c#. Now I want to add the sorting property to the gird view dynamically. I don't want to put the  AllowSorting="true" in the html page. Gridview will be so simple. but sorting will be controlled by the c#.Is it possible? I searched it for a long time but did not find any solution. Please help me as earliest.

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246361/Handle-GridView-OnSorting-using-LINQ

Comment: Dear Frebin, Please note that the example is not the thing I am looking for. AllowSorting="true" is used in asp.net html page. I just want to take the simple girdview and handled the sorting by C#.

Comment: what you mean by "I just want to take the simple girdview" ? can you please be more specific ?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="Grid_details" runat="server" Width="100%"  >

Comment: Now I want to add the sorting properties by c# , not using AllowSorting="true" in html page

Comment: Yes, you can do it. inside the headertemplate, place a linkbutton and on its click event pass the sort param as a commandargument and using that re-bind the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able bind GridView to any IEnumerable object.  Then use LINQ to order those items however you'd like.

```
class DataRecord
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
};

List<DataRecord> data = new List<DataRecord>()
{
    new DataRecord()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Record 1",
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now
    },
    new DataRecord()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Record 2",
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    }
};

gridView.DataSource = data.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);
gridView.DataBind();
```